# How do I handle PGP issues when installing gnome

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gdm

I have just finished a fresh installation of Arch Linux in the same way I have many times, and in accordance with the Arch Linux installation wiki.  I am trying to install gnome and am using the command `pacman -S gnome` as a super user.  I get the following errors when I install gnome;

```
error: libspeech: signature from "Alexander Epaneshikov <email@alex19ep.me>" is unknown trust
Do you want to delete it [Y/n]
error: speechdispatcher: signature from "Alexander Epaneshnikov <email@alex19ep.me>" is unknown trust
Do you want to delete it [Y/n]
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded
```

I have to imagine I am not the only person trying to download gnome that is getting this error.  are these packages that can be merely ignored, or do I need to find a solution to these failed downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signing key for Alexander Epaneshnikov expired on Jan 20, 2022.

It looks like you will need to wait for the package maintainer to update the signing key.

Additional options suggested on the [Arch Linux site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Package_signing#Signature_is_unknown_trust):

- Refreshing your keys with `pacman-key --refresh-keys`, or
- [manually signing the untrusted key locally](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Package_signing#Adding_unofficial_keys), or
- [resetting all the keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Package_signing#Resetting_all_the_keys), or
- setting temporarily `SigLevel` to `TrustAll` (not recommended).

Comment: This did the trick, thank you for the guidance.